# PHP dynamic name of variable

Tags: php

I have this situation:

```
$string = "temp";
$$string = array();

var_dump($temp);

$temp[0] = "hello";
var_dump($temp);
```

That works. But when accessing the array with a variable variable-name, I always get an empty array:

```
$string = "temp";
$$string = array();

$$string[0] = "prova";
var_dump($$string);
```

How can I access the array with a variable name?

Comment: This is what PHP does: `${$string[0]} = "prova";` See: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php

Comment: this code : ${$string[0]} = "prova";
var_dump(${$string}); return empty array

Comment: but I think it will return empty again

Comment: @bomberdini Exactly, that is what PHP does if you don't define it otherwise. What you want and is also by default in PHP 7 is: `${$string}[0] = "prova";`

Answer (score 2):

Because when you used `$$` then it means that you are referring variables.

```
  $string = "temp";
  var_dump($$string);
```

Here `$$string` means that $temp and that is not having value so it is empty result.

In case if you wants to work then use as you suggested.

Use the code as follows:

```
${$string[0]} = "prova";
var_dump(${$string[0]});

output: string(5) "prova"
```

**OR**

```
${$string}[0] = "prova";
var_dump($$string[0]); 

output: array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "prova" }
```

This way you can use `$$` variables of variable in php

[Reference Link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: ok this code work : ${$string[0]} = "prova";
var_dump(${$string[0]});

Comment: Shouldn't it be `${$string}[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "temp";
$$string = array();

$$string[0] = "prova";//here first it get the value of $string[0] and then value of variable of string $string[0], but $string[0] is nothing here that's why you are getting empty in below line
var_dump($$string);
// To get as you want use below line
${$string}[0] = "prova";
var_dump($$string);
```

Check here : https://eval.in/536239

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$$string[0]`, you are calling a variable named in an array called `$string`. Since strings are basically complicated array-like objects, you are calling the character at position 0. So basically, the effect you get is:

```
$string = "temp";
$$string = array();

$$string[0] = "prova";
var_dump($t);
```

because the reference for `$string[0]` is the first character in the string "temp", or "t", so you are really just calling `$t`. What you need is `${$string}[0]`.

If you want the variable to be an array:

```
$var_name = "some_var";
${$var_name} = array();

${$var_name}[0] = "some value";
${$var_name}[1] = "another value";
var_dump(${$var_name});
```

If you want your *name* of your variable to be an array:

```
$var_names = array();
$var_names[0] = "some_var";
$var_names[1] = "another_var";

${$var_names[0]} = "some value";
${$var_names[1]} = "another value";

var_dump(${$var_names[0]});
var_dump(${$var_names[1]});
```

The first is an example of what I think you were trying to do. The second is an example of what you were *actually* doing.

Or, you could just use an associative array:

```
$my_vars = [
    "some_var" => "some value",
    "another_var" => "another value",
];
var_dump($my_vars);
//or loop
foreach ($my_vars as $key => $value)
{
    var_dump($my_vars[$key]);
    //or echo
    echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br>";
    //or set
    $my_vars[$key] = "new calculated value + " . $value;
}

var_dump($my_vars);
```